# Best Web Framework for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have hacking a little with MongoDB and I want to try to use MongoDB for a whole website. We will give also a try for binary files stocking in MongoDB.

We currently using Ruby on Rails and we also like Django. I know there is already some implementations for this two framework with MongoDB (Mongoid and MongoMapper for Ruby) but in fact I am not reluctant to learn something new. :-)

What do you think is the best web plateform/framework to use MongoDB in production ?

Comment: Rather than asking a potentially contentious question, why don't you ask instead, "what tools and libraries can I use with MongoDB and either Ruby on Rails or Django?" this will help stimulate a useful conversation.

Comment: - Meteor.js - it has mini-mongo, by the people that created Apollo. It's gotten new ownership.
- also there's the MEAN stack - https://www.mongodb.com/mean-stack

Comment: - oh yeah there's the MERN stack as well - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-modern-application-stack-part-1-introducing-the-mean-stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working with and on [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/), an "object-document mapper" (like an ORM, but for MongoDB) and Django. It has fairly complete support for MongoDB's data types and CRUD operations, and some nice helpers for aggregation and map-reduce.

(Shameless plug:) You can see my use of some of these features in [Nymwit](http://nymwit.leafhopper.net/), an online word game I built with mongoengine and Django, and corresponding source code in [my github](https://github.com/dcrosta/nymwit).

Comment: I googled this same question for the very reason that I'm currently using mongoengine with Django, yet feel that so much of Django default behavior stops working or becomes incredibly buggy (e.g. Class-based Views, Forms, Django Admin), that I was hoping a more reliable framework exists for this. There are solutions for Forms and Django admin, but as I said, right now they are so buggy that I spend most of my time patching it up instead of getting things done.